# How to show certain images for certain values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, web

So, I'm making this application. What I basically want to do is to show the current temperature, and then show an image of someone wearing a coat or an image of someone not wearing a coat.
I already have the current temp showing, (I'm using an API for that value) But I can't figure out how to do the image part.
I'm using HTML, and Javascript (with JQuery and JSON to use with the API).
I know that I prob. need to use an if statement, but I don't know how to use images in javascript.
I'm inserting the temp into a table, and I would like for the image to be in the same row as the temp in the table.

**The Javascript and the HTML(it's pretty basic) is below**

```js
(function() {
 "use strict";
 
 var main = function() {
  var url = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=MY_PRIVATE_KEY&num_of_days=2&format=JSON&callback=?';
  $.getJSON(url, function(weatherResponse) {
   console.log(weatherResponse);
   var $weatherTable = $('<table>');
   var response = weatherResponse.data.current_condition[0];
   var count = 0;
                for (var prop in response) {
                    if (count == 16) { 
            var $item = $('<tr>');
            var $itemProp = $('<td>').text(prop);
            var $itemVal = $('<td>').text(response[prop]);
            $item.append("Temperature feels like: ");
            $item.append($itemVal);
            $weatherTable.append($item);
                    }
                    count = count+1;
                }
   
   $('main').append($weatherTable);
  });
 };
 
 $(document).ready(main);
}());
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Weather</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <header>
   <h1>Weather</h1>
  </header>
  
  <main>
      
  </main>
  
  <footer>
   <p>Made by </p>
  </footer>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='sun.js'></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few methods you can use.  I prefer the innerHTML method which rewrites the HTML contents of an element to whatever you want which makes it very flexible.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myImg"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
if ($itemVal > 50) {
    document.getElementById("myImg").innerHTML = '<img src="./images/img1.jpg">';
} else {
    document.getElementById("myImg").innerHTML = '<img src="./images/img2.jpg">';
}
```

Alternately you can change just the src attribute of an image:

**HTML**

```
<img id="myImg" src="./images/img1.jpg">
```

**JavaScript**

```
if ($itemVal > 50) {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src='./images/img1.jpg';
} else {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src='./images/img2.jpg';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran the code, I get error 400: parameter key is missing from the url.  Is that intentional or did you copy and paste from their api documentation?  Anyway.  The way how you add an image is by doing:

```
var $img = $("<img>").attr("src","http://example.com/test.png");
$img.appendTo($item);
```

OR:

I noticed you are using .text() to replace the contents of td.  What if you used .html().  .html() allows you to add html directly into the td.  So you coul do:

```
$item.html("<img src='" + src + "' />");
```

Just wanted to add that in case they are sending you HTML to insert into your web application.

Comment: Sorry, I excluded my API key(since it's private and I had to create an account to gain one.) So you can't run the code

Comment: Could you extrapolate  from my example?  Any questions on hwo to add an image and set the src tag?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `<img>` tag and set the `src`attribute with javascript:

```js
// START demo code, random sun or rain
var images = {rain: 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/rain-clipart-789e6b6991418ddbf20bc8f9f7a3bdfc.jpg', sun: 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/clipart-sun-11971486551534036964ivak_Decorative_Sun.svg.med.png'}
var doesItRain = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
var imageUrl = doesItRain ? images.rain : images.sun;
// END demo code, just fill imageUrl and use the following line
$('#weather').attr('src', imageUrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>Weather</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <img id="weather" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="Weather">
</main>
```

The image is initially filled with a transparent gif and will then be changed to the weather image by your script.